# Sending mail with api data using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, email

I need to send mail to the admin with the inserted data using APi function , 
the function is look like that

```
  public function requestbookingresort_post()
    {
        $languageid = $this->input->post('languageId');
        $resort_id = $this->input->post('resortId');
        $booking_from = $this->input->post('bookingFrom');
        $booking_to = $this->input->post('bookingTo');
        $contact_name = $this->input->post('contactName');
        $contact_email = $this->input->post('contactEmail');
        $contact_phone = $this->input->post('contactPhone');
        $userid = $this->input->post('userId');

        if (empty($languageid))
        {
            $languageRecord = getDefaultlanguage();
            $languageid = $languageRecord->languageid;
        }
        $language_file = languagefilebyid($languageid);
        $this->lang->load($language_file, $language_file);

        if (empty($resort_id) || empty($booking_from) || empty($booking_to) || empty($contact_name) || empty($contact_email) || empty($contact_phone))
        {
            $arr['status'] = 'error';
            $arr['statusMessage'] = lang('error_in_booking');
            $arr['data'] = array();
        }
        else
        {
            $dataArray = array(
                "languageid" => $languageid,
                "userid" => empty($userid) ? "0" : $userid,
                "resortid" => $resort_id,
                "bookingfrom" => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($booking_from)),
                "bookingto" => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($booking_to)),
                "contactname" => $contact_name,
                "contactemail" => $contact_email,
                "contactphone" => $contact_phone,
                "requestdatetime" => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
            );
            $this->load->model("Resort_model");
            $booking_id = $this->Resort_model->saveBookingRequest($dataArray);

            if (empty($booking_id))
            {
                $arr['status'] = 'error';
                $arr['statusMessage'] = lang('error_occurred');
                $arr['data'] = array();
            }
            else
            {

                $arr['status'] = 'success';
                $arr['statusMessage'] = lang('booking_request_submit');
                $arr['data'] = array();
            }
        }

        $response = array(
            "response" => $arr
        );

        $this->set_response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED); // CREATED (201) being the HTTP response code
    }
```

But i'm new at codeigniter and didn't know how to get this passed data from the database to send mail with that to the admin mail or something ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```
public function requestbookingresort_post()
{
  // Your operations
  $response = array(
        "response" => $arr
  );
  $this->sendMail($response)
  $this->set_response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_CREATED); // CREATED (201) being the HTTP response code
}
public function sendMail($response)
{
    $settings=$this->Some_model->getEmailSettings();
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // we are going to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // enabled SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  // prefix for secure protocol to connect to the server
    $mail->Host       = $settings->host;                    // setting GMail as our SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = $settings->port;                    // SMTP port to connect to GMail
    $mail->Username   = $settings->email;                   // user email address
    $mail->Password   = $settings->password;                // password in GMail
    $mail->SetFrom($settings->sent_email, $settings->sent_title);       //Who is sending the email
    $mail->AddReplyTo($settings->reply_email,$settings->reply_email);   //email address that receives the response
    $mail->Subject    = "Your Booking has been confirmed";
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $body = $this->load->view('path/email_template', $response, true);
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $destination = $response['contactEmail']; // Who is addressed the email to
    $mail->AddAddress($destination);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $data['code']=300;
        $data["message"] = "Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

Make sure you have [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) in your libraries and you are loading the library in your constructor and I hope you are keeping Email settings in your database. If not you can manually provide host, port, username and password fields

Comment: Can you tell me that line where's come from : 
$body = $this->load->view('path/email_template', $response, true);

Comment: oh this line is used to load your HTML email template if you are using any. its much easier to load a view instead of creating one here

Comment: I guess i need to upload composer for "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2" ? 
Or it's not going to work with me right ?

Comment: or you can clone it from git

Comment: It's working with me now , but i can't get the response array from the first function to the message content >> how can i do that ?

Comment: its because you need to pass the index response itself while calling the sendMail function. like $this->sendMail($response['response'])